# No ROS 'sourceing' anymore after installing rosdep2

Tags: ros

My ROS-system was working pretty well.

Then, I installed **rosdep** by using `sudo apt install python-rosdep2`, which ended fine without showing any issues. Then I issued

```
sudo rosdep init
sudo rosdep update
```

which also ended without showing issues.

But now, my ROS-installation seems to be broken because I can't source my ROS any more!

For example, typing ROS-commands, such as

`roscore` or `rqt`

results in:

[image]

Sourcing, as usual with `source /opt/ros/meldoic/setub.bash` makes no difference.

What has happened? How to fix this?

Additional Info:

Typing `ros<tab><tab>` only shows me the following options anymore:

[image]

Where is all the rest gone?

Answer (score 2):

Install ROS properly again using (Just execute this command, don't worry nothing will be installed twice)
`sudo apt-get update` 
`sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-desktop-full`

also source your ROS packages using (there seems to be a typo in what you've typed above) 
`source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` 
You can add this line to your `.bashrc` file so your ROS automatically get  sourced everytime you open any terminal.

Answer (score 2):

`rosdep update` should be run without sudo. [ROS wiki/rosdep](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdep).

```bash
sudo rosdep init
rosdep update ## without sudo
```

Running `rosdep update` again might solve your problem, although I haven't encountered this specific problem myself. Further steps to investigate could be to search for the commands you are missing (rqt, rostopic). For example search for `roscore`:

```bash
find /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/bin -iname roscore
```

`$ROS_DISTRO` might need to be manually to your ROS distribution (for example noetic).

*Edit*:
The following `rosdep` command will attempt to fix the permission issue.

```bash
rosdep fix-permissions
```

According to the `rosdep` man page:

`rosdep fix-permissions`: "Recursively change the permissions of the user's ros home directory. May require sudo.  Can be useful to fix permissions after calling "rosdep update" with sudo accidentally."

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the ROS distribution melodic, it's likely that installing python-rosdep2 removed much of it from your system if you didn't pay attention to the apt prompts.

If you're using the packages.ros.org sources following the official installation you should be using `python-rosdep` not `python-rosdep2` which comes from the [Upstream repositories](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

The same issue was found [here](https://answers.ros.org/question/353082/missing-packages-after-installing-rosdep-based-on-python3-rosdep2-in-noetic/) for `python3-rosdep2` and noetic but it's the same conflict.

Your solution will be to switch back to `python-rosdep` and reinstall your melodic packages.

Note that the answer by @pvl is sill important that you shouldn't use sudo rosdep update.

And I would recommend looking a little closer at what happens when you run apt and say yes/no to the prompts. `ended fine without showing any issues` likely also told you it was uninstalling most of melodic at the same time. (It was successful and exited cleanly, is not necessarily the same as doing what you wanted.)